Shape optimization for a given positive function
Consider a positive function $f(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider also a bounded region in the space, say a ball $B(0,R)$. I want to find
$$ \min_{\Omega \subset B(0,R)} \int_\Omega f \text{  with  } |\Omega|=1.$$
I also want to impose some additional assumptions on the shape of $\Omega$, like some simmetry and the location of specific points, moreover it is connected and regular (it's actually a diffeomorphic image of a ball centered in the origin and of unitary volume). But the question is: how does one in general find a minimum? If $f$ is explicit, is there hope to find an explicit solution? I know some calculus of variations, but I never worked with shape optimization, I feel like the main ideas (variations, convexity, some sort of Euler-Lagrange equations...) should be the same, but what's the general path one takes to find the optimal shape?


What is $|\Omega|$? 2. Is the integral Riemann or Lebesgue?



It's the measure of $\Omega$ 2. Lebesgue


You might work with a parameterization of $\Omega$, say $\Omega(t)$, meeting your side constraints as well as $\int_{\Omega(t)}, dx =1$, more or less flows or deformations you’d see in continuum mechanics.

Without any restrictions on the shape of $\Omega$, it's just a matter of taking the set where $f$ is the least. Technically, define $F : [0, \infty) \to \left[ 0, \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3 \right]$ as
$$F(y) = | \{ x \in B(0, R) : f(x) \leqslant y \} |.$$
$F$ is right-continuous (and generally cdf-like), so there is a least $y_0 \in [0, \infty)$ such that $F(y_0) \geqslant 1$. The set
$$\Omega_0 = \{ x \in B(0, R) : f(x) < y_0 \}$$
satisfies $|\Omega_0| = \lim_{y \to y_0^-} F(y) \leqslant 1$. It should now be clear that the minimum is realized by the set $\Omega = \Omega_0 \cup \Omega_1$, where $\Omega_1$ is any subset of $f^{-1}[ \{ y_0 \} ]$ of measure $1 - |\Omega_0|$.

Just out of curiosity, is there a more calculus-of-variations-like approach in a less general situation? Like, take some variation of the set just like one does in variational problems?

I can't say for sure, but I would not expect such an approach to exist. At least it would heavily depend on the specific conditions that you want the set to satisfy.
